# Проблема с URL-картинкой

Tags: url

Возникла такая проблема, я увидел в своей ленте ВКонтакте картинку и решили отправить ее другому пользователю. Скопировал адрес ссылки, отправил, а другой пользователь говорит что у него выдается ошибка. Проверил — адрес тот. У меня открывается, у пользователя ошибка. Это же просто картинка, как так может быть?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вероятно, картинка имеет ограничения по доступу (из закрытой группы, например). Однако, такой вопрос не совсем соответствует тематике StackOverflow